# Can I include the installation of other software in a Python Setup?

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm a complete newbie with regards to Python programming (also programming in general) and just finished my first program. Now I want to convert my program and create a Setup file. For my program to work, I needed to install two other software/programs and for other people to use it, they would need to do the same. I want to include the other two programs and its installation directly into my Setup. The question now is two-fold: is that legally allowed? The programs are free and accessible online. If yes, how do I do that? My idea is to in the end have a zip-file that already has the installation file of these other two programs in there and then just have other people install Setup and everything is taken care of. Without requiring the other person to install everything individually.

Every answer is appreciated. Please let me know if I need to be more specific.

**Edit for clarity:** Maybe I can be a little bit more specific. The program I'm writing works with audio input and outputs. For my program to work, I need to have Virtual Cable installed. Obviously, this is not installed on computers per default, so I will need everyone who uses my software to install it. I would like to include the installation of Virtual Cable directly into my setup file when I share it with others. I want to include the installation file for Virtual Cable in the zip-folder and automatically install it to the other users computer. vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm

In the end, I want to create a setup.exe that installs Virtual Cable (and potential other requirements, not sure yet) and then have a mainprogram.exe that will just run as needed. Sorry, if I'm mixing the terms up - new to this.

Comment: I think you can be a little more specific, I don't know if your other programs are python libraries or World of Warcraft game. But I'd assume that python setup file is only for python stuff and doesn't have more applications.

Comment: So, if you want to create an executable from your python program + its dependencies, you should see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen

Comment: Thank you for the answers much appreciated. Maybe I can be a little bit more specific. The program I'm writing works with audio input and outputs. For my program to work, I need to have Virtual Cable installed. Obviously, this is not installed on computers per default, so I will need everyone who uses my software to install it. I would like to include the installation of Virtual Cable directly into my setup file when I share it with others. I want to include the installation package in the zip-folder and automatically install it to the other users computer. https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

No worries if you are new to programming, we've all been there. To answer to your questions:

1. Yes, I don't think there are legal issues when it come to sharing a .exe file (keep in mind that as long as its not for illegal stuff such as spammer, malware, bots that do malicious stuff, those are not accepted but otherwise all is good)
2. You can use a library called "pyinstaller" (`pip install pyinstaller`), and it should do all the work for you, such as getting the libraries that are you using and stuff like that. After you need to go to your command prompt and run `pyinstaller YOURFILE.py`. This should create an exe file for your program and a lot of other stuff (files).

Now, when it comes to make a setup installer you can use an app called NSIS (here is the download link: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download). You need to compress your file (which you already applied pyinstaller on) into a zip file. Then enter into NSIS and add your file in it (1st option), and all should be good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, much appreciated. Maybe I can be a little bit more specific. The program I'm writing works with audio input and outputs. For my program to work, I need to have Virtual Cable installed. Obviously, this is not installed on computers per default, so I will need everyone who uses my software to install it. I would like to include the installation of Virtual Cable directly into my setup file when I share it with others. I want to include the installation file in the zip-folder and automatically install it to the other users computer. https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm

Comment: just add the necessary Virtual Cable files in the files after you have applied the py installer, put the already applied pyinstaller file of your program and the VC file and then zip them and make an exe with NSIS